# can you please tell me what does mean these two lines of codes in R

Tags: r

I understand the first one, but the result that I am getting is not the summation of items 4 to 33 in all.hadm$elix.index column, did I get it wrong?

```
for (i in 1:dim(all.hadm)[1])
    all.hadm$elix.index[i] <- sum(elix[i,4:33])
```

here I got confused with c(1:3), does it mean the columns 1 to 3 in the comp.cand.exp data frame?
can you explain this whole line for me?

```
temp1 <- comp.cand.exp[comp.cand.exp$codec != '',c(1:3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:dim(all.hadm)[1]){
    all.hadm$elix.index[i] <- sum(elix[i,4:33])}
```

The second line of code imputes to temp1 the columns 1 to 3 of dataframe comp.cand.exp for rows where $codec isn't missing or empty.

Comment: I wrote it, you just forgot the {} in your loop